# pg_restore: using the -L (use-list) option not working

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I every now and then restores a db-dump. To save time and I want to exclude some large un-needed tables.
I try to use the -L (use-list) option but when running the pg_restor command it does not work.
I get the same result even if I'm using a un-edited list.

This is the command I use:

*pg_restore -v -U [user] -L "restore.pgdump.list" -d [dbname]-h localhost -p 5432 [dump-file]*

This is the result:

*pg_restore: [archiver] WARNING: line ignored: ÿþ*

*pg_restore: connecting to database for restore*

*Password:*

*pg_restore: implied data-only restore*

If I go with the same command without the L-option the database is restored correctly.

Would much appreciate your help

Peter

Comment: Could there be weird characters (BOM?) in the file?

Comment: Convering the use-list-file to utf-8 without BOM solved the problem. Many thanks!